# How to get the ID of a page from the url?

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

```
I need to get this: 1606321809619553

From that: https://www.facebook.com/Free-Travel-Vacations-1606321809619553/?ref=br_rs

This: barackobama

From that: https://www.facebook.com/barackobama/

and This: barackobama

From that: https://www.facebook.com/barackobama
```

I tried this code:

```
identifier = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/"))
```

but it only work when there is not the final slash url ( like in the last case above ).

Comment: This will be quite difficult if there is not consistency with your URLs.

Comment: google for "regular expressions" (regex)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can leverage regexp

```
var re = /^https:\/\/www\.facebook\.com\/([-\w]+)/;

re.exec("https://www.facebook.com/Free-Travel-Vacations-1606321809619553/?ref=br_rs")[1]
=> "Free-Travel-Vacations-1606321809619553" //then use string manipulation

re.exec("https://www.facebook.com/barackobama/")[1]
=> "barackobama"

re.exec("https://www.facebook.com/barackobama")[1]
=> "barackobama"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that does what you want, using [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) with the alternation operator `|` to work with the two scenarios:

```js
function getIdFromFBUrl(url) {
    var regexp = /^https?:\/\/(www\.)?facebook\.[a-z]+\/((?:[a-zA-Z-]*)([0-9]+)|([a-z]*))/;
    var match = url.match(regexp);
    var id = match[3] || match[4];
    return id;
}


// Tests:

var tests = [
  "https://www.facebook.com/Free-Travel-Vacations-1606321809619553/?ref=br_rs",
  "https://www.facebook.com/barackobama/",
  "https://www.facebook.com/barackobama"
];

tests.forEach(function(url) {
    document.write(url + '<br>=> ' + getIdFromFBUrl(url) + '<br><br>');
});
```